# How to extract pattern from a word

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to perl, I have come across a scenario where I have to extract `D[number]` from a word.

example : 
If input string is `D11C1`, `D11` should be extracted

If input string is `D1C12`, `D1` should be extracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
$word =~ /.*(D\d+).*/;
my $res = $1;
```

\d+ - matches at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

for my $string (qw( D11C1 D1C12 )) {
    my ($extracted) = $string =~ /D[0-9]+/g;
    say $extracted;
}
```

`D` matches itslef, `[0-9]` matches digits, `+` means the digit can be repeated one or more times. The `/g` at the end, in this case, just makes the expression return the matching part of the string. See [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre) for details.

Comment: I think using the /g to return the part of the string that matches the expression is a bit of an advanced use of the flag, and isn't really what /g is for. You're better off using parens to specify the bits of the string to extract i.e. my ($extracted) = $string =~ /^(D\d+)C\d+/

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($d) = $input =~ m/(D\d+)/;
```

Test:

```
perl -E 'while(my $input = shift) { my ($d) = $input =~ m/(D\d+)/; say $d }' D11C1 D1C1
D11
D1
```